# Is the 'scroll' event guaranteed to be fired when scrolling programatically?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In Chrome, if I have an `onscroll` handler:

```
document.body.onscroll = function () {console.log('foo')}
```

... and I scroll the document programatically:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 7
```

... then the `onscroll` handler fires.

Can I depend on this behaviour across browsers, or will some only fire the handler for scrolling caused by user action? Is this specced anywhere?

Comment: Are you strictly referring to setting `scrollTop`? This may (hopefully) be helpful... https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrolltop

Comment: @Dom Not necessarily - I imagine `scrollLeft` has the same behaviour. Why? And what's the significance of the spec link?

Comment: My mistake, I provided `scrollTop` rather than an `onscroll` browser spec link. MDN provides their [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll#Browser_Compatibility) but that only shows support for edge/chrome, the others are still undetermined. I came across the [W3C's UI Events Spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-scroll), but it's status is obsolete. I'll post any relevant specs if I come across one.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what (if anything) the *spec* says about this, but I have now tested and confirmed that the handler *does* fire in the latest versions of:

- Chrome (desktop)
- Chrome (mobile)
- Firefox
- Edge
- Safari (desktop)

If there's a platform you want to test, pop open https://jsfiddle.net/14nckcw1/4/embedded/result/ on it and wait; if you see an alert after 1 second, then programmatic scrolling fires the `onscroll` handler on that platform. I don't know of anywhere this isn't the case.